# Selenium, удаленный веб-драйвер не выполняет действия как локальный бразузер

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Имеется selenoid в контейнере, проверяю в firefox 61 и chrome 68, python3 selenium скрипт.
Задача в magento 1.x выполнить регистрацию пользователя.

---

Проблема при нажатии кнопки регистрации, в настольном браузере регистрация проходит, в удаленном браузере по нажатию кнопки обновляется страница и заполнение форм сбрасывается.

Локально выполняя запросы из консоли браузера или Katalon Recoder все отрабатывает успешно.
При выполнении скрипта через удаленный веб-драйвер испытываю проблему, пробовал различные методы, все приводят к единому результату.

Пробовал:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/section/div/div/div/div/div/form/div[2]/button")).click()

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='col-2']/button[@type='submit']").submit()

driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[.='Зарегистрироваться']"))

driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

И в таком духе, страница просто обновляется, куда копать, что смотреть, мистика какая-то.

Сама кнопка:

```
<div class="col-2">
    <button type="submit" title="Зарегистрироваться" class="button ">
        <span>Зарегистрироваться</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

Почему удаленный веб-драйвер Selenium выполняет задачу не так как настольный браузер?

Comment: Вы пробовали вставлять sleep или задержки?
Вы уверены что этот элемент присутствует в удалённом браузере?

Comment: Задержки проставлял, пробовал сам нажать кнопку подключившись через VNC, проблема остается в firefox и chrome.

Comment: а что за проблемы испытываете ?

Comment: Из настольного браузера при нажатии кнопки выполняется регистрация
Из управляемого веб-драйвером при нажатии кнопки обновляется страница

Comment: Все оказалось банально, cookie домен кто-то из ребят сменил на тестовом сайте, в настольных браузерах все работало, а в контейнере без ошибки запрос уходил в другое окружение.